# Sketch circular icon export clipped

Tags: export, sketch-app, mask

I am a relative sketch / design newbie. I am trying to creating a simple check mark icon embedded in a green circle.

[image: green exported image]

The problem is the clipping on top of the circle on all sides. My sketch file organization looks like this.

[image]

It is basically two lines at an angle and an oval. I tried using the oval as a mask and without mask. Not sure what I am doing wrong. The figure looks good on sketch

The sketch file is uploaded on dropbox [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2ha9kg92l6zderf/sketch_circle_file.sketch?dl=0).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Problem is that your circle is bigger than your artboard.

[image: Sketch Screenshot]

The circle is 24 x 24 px big as well as your artboard. But you have a border of 1px around it, which is center aligned. This means your circle is actually 24.5 x 24.5 px big. So when you export your icon 0.5px will be cut away.

So what you can do is either delete the border by unchecking the checkmark in the *Borders* section or you can increase the art board size.
You can do this by clicking on your artboard (in your case *Edit Circle Selected*) in the outline panel on the left and adjust the size on the right.

Answer (score -4):

Change border 'position' from 'center' to 'inside'. It will help.